# Acumatica ERP Import Closed Invoice from other ERP system

Tags: acumatica

Currently Acumatica ERP provides Import scenarios for import from other Systems, but to import closed Invoice it's needed to import it and process.
We don't want to process the invoice and import it as already closed invoice.

How can I do this? Will I have to import data directly to Database?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid Database direct entries. What if you add a customization on the page you are trying to import to allow it to go direct to closed?

You can use the graph `IsImport` to know the screen is running as an import to perform special functionality for import scenarios only. I am not sure, but keep in mind that screen based API might also set/use `IsImport`. There is also an `IsContractBasedAPI` but don't think that applies for your scenario.

For example maybe you allow the status field to be enabled when the process is running IsImport and adjust your import scenario to to set the status. Or add a custom button only available for import that does a direct close process.

Comment: I'm currently creating new Page which allows to set Status Closed without Processing Invoice. I currently have some problems but I think I will solve them soon